# nwbuilder won't build normal flavors

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

I have the `nwbuilder` module installed on my machine and every time I try to make a build it only uses the "sdk" version of NW.js. I literally tried to manually download the "normal" NW.js and put it inside nwbuilder's cache directory but still didn't budge. I also added this piece to my manifest file (package.JSON) since it's how their GitHub said it should work :

`"options":{
    "flavor": "normal"
  }`

Still won't work and it somehow forces the download or the build process of the sdk flavor only. This is what I run in my command prompt: `nwbuild -p win64 -v 0.20.2 Desktop/app -o Desktop/app2`

Answer (score 0):

Have a closed issue on nw-builder github about that.

You can update a nw-builder to work it.

Follow the issue

[issue #440](https://github.com/nwjs-community/nw-builder/issues/440)